# How Does array_map() Work Behind the Scenes? - PHP

Tags: php, array-map

I implemented array_map() as follows:

```
$example = array(' spacedemail@test.com', 'anotherSpacedEmail@test.com ');

$result = array_map(function($email) {
    return trim($email);
}, $example);

// $result now has each item trimmed
// IE: 'spacedemail@test.com', 'anotherSpacedEmail@test.com' ..
```

This got me to wondering...

**Q** How exactly is array_map() working behind the scenes?

Comment: That way: http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/ext/standard/array.c#4166

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Comment: What do you mean by "wondering"? Is there anything you don't understand about the result you've received?

Answer (score 1):

You can also explain this way by using a closure to a function :

```
function map($func, $items)
{
    $result = [];

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $result[] = $func($item);
    }

    return $result;
}

$result = map(function($email) {
    return trim($email);
}, $example);
```

Comment: Please add some more explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. The OP did not ask how to **use** that function, but how it is "working behind the scenes"